# ubuntu terminal check if process is running

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I need to check in ubuntu terminal if process `node` is running so that i can use two different commands then if is running or not.

i try copy paste this code in ubuntu terminal:

```
if pgrep -x "node" > /dev/null then echo "Running" else echo "Stopped" fi
```

in terminal i get only `>` and no output...and i was expacting to output: `Running` or `Stopped`

But it stucks on `>`

How can i check in terminal without using external sh file to get information if node process is running or not? I im executing this in node ssh command on another server so i try copy paste this code on my server local but is not go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got three missing semicolons:

```
if pgrep -x "node" > /dev/null; then echo "Running"; else echo "Stopped"; fi
```